# Time delta to pull all the unique entries from an API call

Tags: python, api, datetime, cloud, timedelta

I am pulling a set of alarms from a cloud platform with an API call, I want to fetch all the alarms created in a time frame (example 5 minutes) and I am using windows scheduler to run my code every 5 minutes. So when the code runs again it should give me unique entries of alarms (not the one which are fetched earlier). Here is the function I am using.

```py
search_period= datetime.now() - timedelta(minutes=5)

date_str= f"{search_period.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3]}Z"
```

Comment: what specifically doesn't work as you expect?

Comment: It is giving me duplicate entries , I am not able to find a logic which gives unique entries every time i run the code. for example : code runs at 5 PM , it should give me all the entries populated in (4:55 PM to 5 PM) and so on.

Comment: Can you determine if this is a problem of the time window you specify, or the API itself?

Comment: API call is working fine , I am having hard time to work with time/timedelta